# how to show where data goes from more than zero to zero?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to show this phrase in my data analysis: Whenever gazeAngleVelocity goes from more than zero to zero, that's the start of a fixation. Whenever it goes from zero to greater than zero, that's the end of a fixation. Create a flag whenever this happens.
I have no idea which command would be needed; does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please consider consulting the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Does it to and from exactly zero? Or is this about greater than/less than zero kinds of tests?

Comment: Data are floats, and so far I have exported a plot from normalized data from an excel sheet with 825 rows and five columns. As a result, I see a graph with many peaks and valleys. When it said: when it goes from more than zero to zero, it is the valleys. The mystery could be solved if I counted valleys and peaks and knew their areas and times

Answer (score 1):

You can [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the column to compare the values to the previous ones.

(For this example, I'll use some dummy data.)

```
curr = df["gazeAngleVelocity"]
prev = curr.shift()
df["fixation_start"] = (prev > 0) & (curr == 0)
df["fixation_end"] = (prev == 0) & (curr > 0)
df
```

Which gives:

```
   gazeAngleVelocity  fixation_start  fixation_end
0                0.5           False         False
1                1.1           False         False
2                0.8           False         False
3                0.0            True         False
4                1.1           False          True
5                2.3           False         False
6                0.0            True         False
7                0.0           False         False
```

---

If you want to put the flags on the rows *before* the change, just shift in the other direction, which gets you the *next* values:

```
next_ = curr.shift(-1)
df["fixation_start"] = (curr > 0) & (next_ == 0)
df["fixation_end"] = (curr == 0) & (next_ > 0)
df
```

Which gives:

```
   gazeAngleVelocity  fixation_start  fixation_end
0                0.5           False         False
1                1.1           False         False
2                0.8            True         False
3                0.0           False          True
4                1.1           False         False
5                2.3            True         False
6                0.0           False         False
7                0.0           False         False
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution simply compares a number to the previous number. It might be a bit off depending on if the first number's sign is different from the last. Let me know if this works:

```
a = [1,1,-1,-2,-3,4,5,-3,1]

fixations = []
for index in range(len(a)):
    if a[index-1] > 0 and a[index] < 0:
        fixations.append("fixation_start")
    elif a[index-1] < 0 and a[index] > 0:
        fixations.append("fixation_end")
    else:
        fixations.append("continuation")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I wanna do this: Whenever gazeAngleVelocity goes from more than zero to zero, that's the start of a fixation. Whenever it goes from zero to greater than zero, that's the end of a fixation. Create a flag whenever this happens.
The total number of fixations is the total number of start flags.
The duration of a fixation is the time value between the start and end of a fixation.

Comment: I used this command but it did not work for this purpose

Comment: Just made some edits. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Consider how you can use numpy for vectorized (all array at a time) operations which are faster and (with practice) easier to read and write. In this case, looking at `np.sign(a)` and diff of it might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy array you can compare `a[i]` with `a[i+1]` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4)  

print('complete array:')
print(a)  # [0, 1, 2, 3]

print('all array but first element')
print(a[1:])  # [1, 2, 3]
print('all array but last element')
print(a[:-1])  # [0, 1, 2]

# now we can compare them:

print('positions where next is greater than previous')
print(a[1:] > a[:-1])  # [True, True, True]
```

However, consider that, when removing the first (or last) element, there is one "missing" element, so, the resulting array contains one element less than the original.

In your case, you need to impose two constaints, so you also need an `&` (and). It should be something like:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 2, 1, 0, 11, 2, 3, 2, 1111, 0, 11111])


print('start of a fixation')
print(a[:-1][(a[1:] == 0 ) & (a[:-1] > 0)])  # [1, 1111]


print('end of a fixation')
print(a[1:][(a[1:] > 0 ) & (a[:-1] == 0)])  # [11, 11111]
```